# How to bind two document objects to single jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a custom jquery function that I need to bind to two iframe document objects.

Currently it will work with just one doing something like:

```
$(window.frames["iframeName"].document).bind('textselect', function(e) {

});
```

what I'm looking to do is something like:

```
$(window.frames["iframeName"].document,window.frames["iframeName2"].document).bind('textselect', function(e) {

});
```

Comment: why not to declare variable function above and use two separate binds with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the anonymous function to a named one and use it for both binds, like this:

```
$(window.frames["iframeName"].document).bind('textselect', selectStuff);
$(window.frames["iframeName2"].document).bind('textselect', selectStuff);

function selectStuff(e) {
  //Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an anonymous function - create a named function

```
function myhandler(e)
{
    //body of function
}
```

Then use the named function:

```
$(window.frames["iframeName"].document).bind('textselect', myhandler);
$(window.frames["iframeName2"].document).bind('textselect', myhandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative

```
<body>
    <iframe name="iframe1" src="text.html" width="100px" height="100px" style="border:1px solid #000"></iframe>
    <iframe name="iframe2" src="text.html" width="100px" height="100px" style="border:1px solid #000"></iframe>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        function bindFrameDocuments(eventType, handler) {
            for (var i = 0; i < window.frames.length; i++) {
                $(window.frames[i].document).bind(eventType, handler);
            }
        }

        bindFrameDocuments( 
            'textselect', 
            function(e) {
                // this function runs in the scope of the frame
                window.parent.console.log(e);
            } 
        );

    });

    </script>
</body>
```